# Turn off CSRF token in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csrf

I have a rails app that serves some APIs to an iPhone application.
I want to be able to simply post on a resource without minding on get the correct CSRF token.
I tried some methods that I see here in stackoverflow but it seems they no longer work on rails 3.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

In the controller where you want to disable CSRF the check:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Or to disable it for everything except a few methods:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :except => [:update, :create]
```

Or to disable only specified methods:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:custom_auth, :update]
```

More info: [RoR Request Forgery Protection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer for apps that have a mix of regular browser-accessible forms and API endpoints.  The answer from Markus Proske would be correct if you were absolutely sure you were not going to have any browser-accessible forms in your app.

Comment: Where exactly does this go? What if the controller part of some gem?

Comment: May I ask you if you can answer this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 108):

In Rails3 you can disable the csrf token in your controller for particular methods:

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :create
```

Comment: For anyone reading, note that this is what should go in `ApplicationController`. Mike Lewis' response below (`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`) is how to disable it on per-controller basis, assuming that controller inherits from `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Seems this is unsafe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676018/security-safe-to-disable-csrf-tokens-for-json-rails-calls. What do you think? is it?

Comment: @NudeCanalTroll you mean putting this in the controller where I want it wont work?

Comment: May I ask you if you can answer this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 33):

With Rails 4, you now have the option to write in `skip_before_action` instead of `skip_before_filter`.

```
# Works in Rails 4 and 5
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

or

```
# Works in Rails 3 and 4 (deprecated in Rails 4 and removed in Rails 5)
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: May I ask you if you can answer this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Comment: John Sam, when I have time I'll try and get around to it.