# Post Request to Rails Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, http, activerecord

I'm still new to Rails and am having difficulty sending a post request to my Rails database. Ultimately, I want to have an iOS app frontend with Rails on the backend. At the moment, I have a python script that is sending a post request to my rails server. [Here is the python script](http://pastebin.com/qWPgSTus).
I generated everything else using a scaffold.
Here is what the server is [telling me.](http://pastebin.com/jWx8rVqj)
Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't understand. What is going wrong? for what I see the POST request is working.

Comment: The python script appears to be working, but the data that it sends is not getting written into the database properly. SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "logins" ("created_at", "org", "password", "updated_at", "user_id", "user_name") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 02 Jan 2013 20:49:04 UTC +00:00], ["org", nil], ["password", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 02 Jan 2013 20:49:04 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil], ["user_name", nil]]

Comment: The code should be posted into the question, not into a pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what your problem is. Are you talking about the CSRF warning? Have a look at [the rails documentation on the topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

---

CSRF is a security mechanism that prevents code on other sides from abusing your users's sessions.

Comment: Despite the parameters {"organization"=>"Adams Inc.", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_id"=>"2", "user_name"=>"Marvin"}, all four values that get passed into the database are nil. I added a line to ignore the CSRF warning but this problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that Rails has built in [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection. To successfully post to your Rails script from a Python (or iOS) script, you'll probably need to disable CSRF protection in your Rails app as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669322/turn-off-csrf-token-in-rails-3)

Also curious as to why you're using Python to write your test instead of Ruby. (Or, why you're not using a Python framework instead of Rails if you already know Python?)

Comment: I added a line to ignore the CSRF warning but this problem still persists. Despite the parameters {"organization"=>"Adams Inc.", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_id"=>"2", "user_name"=>"Marvin"}, all four values that get passed into the database are nil. 

Hmm that's a good question. I guess I don't really have a good answer to that.