# Create new person with rest-client post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, restful-authentication

I created an simple demo app, to experiment a little bit:

```
rails new rumba
rails g scaffold People name:string
```

Then i wrote an little programm to make an post request:

```
require 'rest_client'
response = RestClient.post 'localhost:3000/people', :people => {:name => 'Joseph'}
puts response
```

So far it works and generates an new people. 
The only problem im facing is that i think, that this wont work on heroku, because i provide no authentikation token:

```
Started POST "/people" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-09 00:08:10 +0200
Processing by PeopleController#create as XML
Parameters: {"person"=>{"name"=>"Joseph"}}

WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
←[1m←[36mSQL (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO "people" ("created_at", "name", "upd
ated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)←[0m  [["created_at", Sun, 08 Sep 2013 22:08:10 UTC +0
0:00], ["name", "Joseph"], ["updated_at", Sun, 08 Sep 2013 22:08:10 UTC +00:00]]
```

So my question is how can i provide an authentication token in my RestClient.post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create your own authenticity token. You would need to a couple of things.

1. [Turn off csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669322/turn-off-csrf-token-in-rails-3) in Rails.
2. Create an action that would give you an authenticity token in your Heroku app.
3. Make a request to the above mentioned action, then store the authenticity token that is given to you in your app.
4. When a request is sent to your Heroku app, create a filter that verifies the authenticity token before your action saves a person.

Since you are playing around, you could always set the token to a `DateTime` then check for how old the token is to verify it. However, if you ever wanted to do this on a production site, you would have to take much more consideration into how the authenticity token is created.

Comment: Do you know another way to create an new user out of an ruby programm, besides an post-request?

Comment: Besides creating it inside the heroku console via running `heroku run rails console` in your terminal, no. Actually, you could create a bunch of records via a rake task if you just want to create sample data.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693983/rest-client-get-authenticity-token-to-create-new-record