# Using curl to access backend API of Rails app that implements devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, curl, devise

We have a new web app constructed by another developer.  My job was to implement a backend API for other programs to use to exchange XML data with the database.  It was going pretty well, until the main app implemented devise to authenticate users.  I figured I'd be able to tweak the curl command to log in then submit/request data, but it isn't going very well.  I'm trying things like

```
curl --cookie-jar ~/Desktop/cjar --data "user[login]=<username>" --data "user[password]=<pwd>" --data "commit=Sign in" localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

followed by

```
curl --cookie ~/Desktop/cjar --data "<root_node></root_node>" localhost:3000/my_update_method
```

my latest error message is

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

I guess that's better than the redirection messages I was getting, but I'm still not close to knowing what's going on.

I've found a few related posts that make me think this is partly related to devise, and partly related to automatic authentication done by Rails.  When I look at the info being passed by the web page, I see authenticity_token and utf8 params that I don't know how to construct for my curl command.

I can keep trying stuff, but I'm new to both curl and authentication, so I'm sort of shooting in the dark, and hoping that someone can save me some time.  I guess my questions are:

1. Can this be done?
2. Should this be done?  If not, what other options do I have?
3. One post suggested a way around the authentication, but is is possible for only the curl commands to require a login/pwd, but bypass any other validation, without affecting the main web app?

UPDATE 1:

Thanks for all the help, I appreciate it.  The response to the first curl command (listed above) is now just a redirection to the login page, so logging in doesn't seem to take.  Does anyone have any suggestions about where to start debugging that?  Nothing is ever getting into the application, so there's no logging there to look at.  Here's the content of the cookie, if it means anything to anyone:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_localhost FALSE   /   FALSE   0   _glow_session   BAh7B0kiCmZsYXNoBjoGRUZvOiVBY3Rpb25EaXNwxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaAk6CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7ADoMQGNsb3NlZEY6DUBmbGFzaGVzewY6C25vdGljZUkiHFNpZ25lZCBpbiBzdWNjZXNzZnVsbHkuBjsAVDoJQG5vdzBJIg9zZXNzaW9uX2lkBjsARkkiJTIwODc1Y2VjM2ViNzlmZDE3ZjA4ZjVmMDAxNWMxMDU4BjsAVA%3D%3D--d90722b6da386630b33f57902447b440f30d0b2a
```

I've added `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to the controller that handles the api requests, and that eliminated the error I was seeing before.

UPDATE 2:

After some troubleshooting and debugging, I think I may actually be getting logged in okay, but when I execute the second curl, the development.log file shows

```
Started POST "/upsert_experiment" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-16 12:14:12 -0500
Processing by WebServiceController#upsert_experiment as */*
  Parameters: {"experiment_xml"=>"<experiment></experiment>"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

which leads me to think that the authorization is still the problem.

UPDATE 3:

I think the problem is just that `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` isn't working.

I have

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::LdapException do |exception|
    render :text => exception, :status => 500
  end
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

and

```
class WebServiceController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  ...
end
```

With this setup, I get "Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms".  If I comment out the protect_from_forgery line in the superclass, it just works, so the forgery protection is definitely the problem.  I just don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails [CSRF protection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) is preventing you from making this request.

From rails documentation

`CSRF protection automatically include a security token, calculated from the current session and the server-side secret, in all forms and Ajax requests generated by Rails. You won't need the secret, if you use CookieStorage as session storage. If the security token doesn't match what was expected, the session will be reset. Note: In Rails versions prior to 3.0.4, this raised an ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error.`

If you want to skip it, add this line to your controller

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => ["your_update_action"]
```

Comment: This looks promising!  Does it still require the curl command to specify login/password?  Also, what's the best way to specify multiple exempted actions?

Comment: You still have to specify username/password. `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :except => ["action1", "action2"]`

Comment: I'm getting this error:
<h1>Routing Error</h1>
<p><pre>undefined method skip_before_action for ApplicationController:Class</pre></p>
<p>
  Try running <code>rake routes</code> for more information on available routes.
</p>

I have this line in the application controller:
`skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :except => [:upsert_experiment, :upsert_workflow]`

I also tried it with both method names in quotes, instead of as symbols, but I got the same error.  I'll look at the documentation in the morning, but if you see an obvious problem, feel free to let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: Try `skip_before_filter`

Comment: That removed the error, but I still can't log in (see edit in OP).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a CSRF token. This is to prevent cross site request forgery.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by making the request through the Rails app instead.  How would another application access the Rails app if not through curl?

Comment: Edited original answer. Sorry, whognu, I just misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

CSRF stands for Cross Site Request Forgery and is a security protection you can read more about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Essentially rails generates a random token included in the form rendered on the page and it expects to get that token back on form submit. You don't need this protection for an api, but it is important for the web app side. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669322/turn-off-csrf-token-in-rails-3) for methods to disable the CSRF token.

One approach you might take is to use the `token_authenticable` Devise module and authenticate your requests with `auth_token=#{token}`, then skip CSRF protection if an auth token is present.