# PATCH Request to Rails API with React Native returns 422

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, react-native

I am trying to access an API which which does not require authentication. When I use jQuery, my request works fine, but when requesting in React Native, I get `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`. I have tried many ways to post with this token, but can't seem to figure it out.

My code is:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'patch',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: body,
})
```

Comment: whats yr jquery lines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `X-CSRF-Token` headers in your request, or disable Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection. Here are some links that will help you:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper.html#method-i-csrf_meta_tags

[Turn off CSRF token in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669322/turn-off-csrf-token-in-rails-3#answer-18689428)

Answer (score 0):

For CORS requests, use the "include" value to allow sending credentials to other domains:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'patch',
  credentials: 'include'
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: body,
})
```