# protect_from_forgery with: :null_session -- still getting Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, react-native, post

I have a React Native app making POST requests to a Rails backend. Even though I inserted `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in the `ApplicationController`. All the POST requests I make are failing and I'm getting the error:

> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

This is one of the controllers in my Rails backend that I make the POST request to:

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    address = Address.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def create
    address = Address.new(address_params)

    if address.save
      render json: {status: 'address created successfully'}, status: :create
    else
      render json: { errors: address.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
    end
  end 

  def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:streetname, :zipcode, :city, :country)
  end

end
```

I've also tried to `protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }` as I'm sending a JSON POST request, but still I'm getting the same error. Can anyone offer a different solution? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

**Question Update**:

I followed what this guy did in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669322/turn-off-csrf-token-in-rails-3). And I inserted the following instead:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Now I'm not getting "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" as an error, but  I'm still getting an 500 (Internal Server Error) response from my server in the terminal. The values are not being saved for some reason. This is the error, I get:

```
  Address Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("streetname", "zipcode", "city", "country", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["streetname", "Imenstrade 39"], ["zipcode", "1082AK"], ["city", "Amsterdam"], ["country", "The Netherlands"], ["created_at", "2018-08-29 12:23:22.261020"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-29 12:23:22.261020"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:10
   (2.2ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:10
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

Comment: Can you show Address model code?

Comment: class Address < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :senders 
    has_many :receivers
end

Comment: Can you save address like this: address.save! And show output

Comment: Started POST "/addresses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-29 15:02:06 +0200
Processing by AddressesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"address"=>{"streetname"=>"Witte De Westraat", "zipcode"=>"1065FJ", "city"=>"Amsterdam", "country"=>"The Netherlands"}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction

Comment: ↳ app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:10
  Address Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("streetname", "zipcode", "city", "country", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["streetname", "Witte De Westraat"], ["zipcode", "1065FJ"], ["city", "Amsterdam"], ["country", "The Netherlands"], ["created_at", "2018-08-29 13:02:06.301544"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-29 13:02:06.301544"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:10
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:10

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)

Comment: I think its the same error, right?

Comment: Something bad happens  on rendering. Try 
render json: {status: 'address created successfully'}.to_json, status: :create

Comment: Probably you should give a try this tool https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ActionController::API` instead of `ApplicationController`, and I see a syntax error you wrote `status: :create` instead of `status: :created`